# Flutter: Custom Appbar, Floating Action Button and BottomSheet in Master-Detail Layout

Tags: android, flutter, master-detail, scaffold, flutter-appbar

I'm working on an app, that uses a `Master-Detail-Layout`.

So far I'm using two `Scaffolds` in an `Row`. The left side of the layout is wrapped in a `Scaffold` and the right side is also wrapped in a `Scaffold`. But it's probably not the best solution.
If I'm opening the `SideDrawer` with this solution (using two `Scaffolds`), only the left part gets greyed out and the right part stays clear....

Are there other options to get this `Appbar` or to achieve that `FloatingActionButton` or `BottomNavigationSheet` are only on the left side?
Or should I continue using two `Scaffolds`?

Answer (score 1):

**AppBar**

You can develop your app bar from scratch with widgets(Container,Row) since it's different.

**2 scaffolds**

Also for scaffolds you can use Widgets and use one scaffold.

**Floating action button**

For the Floating action button, you can change it's position : 
by wrapping it in a Center widget or use a crossAxisAlignment of CrossAxisAlignment.center on your Column.

I don't recommend using two scaffolds.you cannot guarantee the behavior of the
screen with (keyboard,snackBars..).
I hope that helps you a bit